# Tinymce Paste Plugin allow pasting images when paste_as_text: true,

Tags: tinymce

TinyMce Editor with paste_as_text: true removes all styles and formatting while pasting text copied from other sites. This helps in formatting the text in a standard way on one of our blog site.

However, We want out users to be able to copy and paste images to the editor from their facebook or hosted photo album accounts. But setting paste_as_text: true  does not allow image to be pasted.

Answer (score 1):

Add paste_data_images: true to your settings.